# Make JList Values Unselectable

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I was wondering how to modify a `JList` so that clicking any values would not do anything. I have looked at other questions but none have helped.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved it by using the following class:

```
class DisabledItemSelectionModel extends DefaultListSelectionModel {

    @Override
    public void setSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1) {
        super.setSelectionInterval(-1, -1);
    }
}
```

I instantiated the class here:

`console.setSelectionModel(new DisabledItemSelectionModel());`

Comment: This method still allows the user to select elements with CTRL + Mouse1 click unless selection model is set to `SINGLE_SELECTION`.

Comment: For me, setting selection mode (!) to `SINGLE_SELECTION` does not prevent it. But overriding `public void addSelectionInterval(int index0, int index1)` with the same `super.setSelectionInterval(-1, -1);` does.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your objects in your JList are clickable items, just do `setEnabled(false)` on all the objects you want to disable

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am writing Strings to the JList, so there's no way I could disable Strings.