# Disable JList Cell Selection Property

Tags: java, swing, selection, cell, jlist

I am attempting to display an `array` of `strings` in a `JList`, which is then added to a `JPanel` using `Java Swing`. I am not having a problem displaying the data in the `Jlists`, however I would like to **remove the default property that allows a user to select items in the `Jlist`**. I am attempting to simply display the data to the user. Unfortunately I am unable to locate the property that would allow me to disable this feature. A example of the selection property that I am referring to can be seen here in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EssJ.png).

Perhaps I am using the wrong `Java Swing` component to display this data, but I have research `JTextArea`, `JTable`, etc., and the `JList` seems to fit my needs. Any help is much appreciated.

public static JComponent createList(ArrayList inputData) {

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(false);
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);

    String[] displayData= {Data.get(0),Data.get(1),Data.get(2),Data.get(3)};
    JList<String> displayDataList= new JList<String>(displayData);
    displayDataList.setFont(sysDataList.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN)); 
    panel.add(displayDataList);

    return panel;
}
```

Comment: Show your code which you tried to solve this.

Comment: Also there are many solutions on this very site, like this duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863780/make-jlist-values-unselectable that already has duplicates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I achived this by implementing a NoSelection SelectionModel. SelectionModels are responsible for handling selection events, see [ListSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html) Example:

```
public final class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame();
       frame.setSize(500, 500);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       JList<Object> view = new JList<Object>();
       view.setSelectionModel(new NoSelectionModel());
       view.setListData(new Object[] {"String 1 ", "String 2"});
       frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(view));

       frame.setVisible(true);
     }
   });
 }

 private static class NoSelectionModel extends DefaultListSelectionModel {

   @Override
   public void setAnchorSelectionIndex(final int anchorIndex) {}

   @Override
   public void setLeadAnchorNotificationEnabled(final boolean flag) {}

   @Override
   public void setLeadSelectionIndex(final int leadIndex) {}

   @Override
   public void setSelectionInterval(final int index0, final int index1) { }
 }
}
```

You have to remember: If the user cannot select anything he can also not copy paste anything. Furthermore, the keyboard scroll behavior is little strange.

Comment: – That has worked perfectly and is much appreciated. I simply had to call the following:

      displayDataList.setSelectionModel(new NoSelectionModel());

Comment: This solution doesn't work if you hold the touch Ctrl while selecting items.. Is there a way to prevent that ?

Comment: Yes, there is, the solution is in the comment of the accepted answer of this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863780/make-jlist-values-unselectable    --- we need to set the mode SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION to the list.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Java, the selection is also blocked when `setEnabled()` is set to `false`. Although there is a particularity when you have a `JList` inside a panel (`JScrollPane`) and you try to recursively disable all elements inside of it.
Here is a method that will help you with that:

```
public void setComponentStatus(JComponent panel, Boolean status) {
        try {
            panel.setEnabled(status);
            Component[] components = panel.getComponents();
            
            for (Component component : components) {
                if (component instanceof JPanel) {
                    setComponentStatus((JComponent) component, status);
                } else {
                    if (component instanceof JScrollPane)
                        ((JScrollPane) component).getViewport().getView().setEnabled(status);
                    component.setEnabled(status);
                }
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Impossible to complete change the status of the panel: " + panel + " or one of its components to status:" + status, e);
        }
    }
```

The core feature I'm trying to point out is this:

`((JScrollPane) component).getViewport().getView().setEnabled(status);`

Answer (score -1):

`JList` is supposed to be selectable. Note the absence of `NO_SELECTION` in `ListSelectionModel` interface.

If you want to just display the items, the best option is to display a list of `JLabel`s in a panel rather than using `JList`.

Comment: Really ? You would even use hundreds of JLabels if you have a considerable ArrayList of objects to display ?