# Java disable mouse click over the jList

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlist

I made a game "Who Wants To Be A Millionaire" with jList filed. In the jList I listed the prises see this picture below

[image]

The game is started with the prise number 1 and increase the number if the answer was OK. If I move the mouse over the prises I can modify the prise position with the mouse click as well. This is what I want to disable. The jList need to have only for show the prises without modify with the mouse click.
I also try to use disable of the jList but than all the colors are changed and I don't find where can I adjust the disabled colors.

What is the best solution for my need ?

Comment: Do you want the users not to be able to select JList cells with mouse? Or you want them not to change the values only?

Comment: In that case is the same. User can't modify the jList values. jList must be a display for the prises only without any mouse modification. The modification do the program only.

Comment: For the solution I use the jList events.  jListMouseEntered --> index = jList.getSelectedIndex();  For the jListMouseExited and jListMousePressed and jListMouseDragged --> jList.setSelectedIndex(index);

Comment: Please add your code (minimal) so that we can run it and understand your problem and requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The **simplest** way to achieve that is to add a [ListSelectionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to restore the proper index into your `JList`.

Take a look at an example:

```
list.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        list.setSelectedIndex(myIndex);

    }
});
list.setSelectedIndex(0); //0 plays no role, since listener will select myIndex
```

The selected index will always remain my index, no matter what.

**Note:** If you want to change the index later, you must change the value of `myIndex` variable **without forgetting firing the selection listener as well**. More accurately:

```
myIndex = 15;
list.setSelectedIndex(0); //0 plays no role, since the selection listener uses myIndex
```

---

Another way (**more complex** in my opinion) is to read and follow [Disable JList Cell Selection Property.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31669350/disable-jlist-cell-selection-property)